# Varnish installer cannot find PCRE when it is already installed

Tags: mac-osx, varnish, mac, pcre

I am trying to install Varnish-Cache 4 on my Mac OS X 10.9.3.

But I get this error:

```
checking for PCRE... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libpcre) were not met:

No package 'libpcre' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables PCRE_CFLAGS
and PCRE_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

The thin is PCRE is installed. I can find it in /usr/bin/. When I do man pcre I get it's documentation.

Any ideas? I am not sure how to solve this.

In config.log I found this:

```
configure:14734: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "libpcre"
Package libpcre was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libpcre.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libpcre' found
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is run-time libraries.
You may also need libpcre-devel package installed as well. That includes headers and libraries requires to link other code during compilation.
Additionally, check that the version of PCRE you have installed is compatible with Varnish-Cache 4.

You can find additional information in `config.log` file.

Comment: Where do I find: libpcre-devel? And I have the most recent PCRE. I compiled it.

Comment: It may be possible that your compiled PCRE is installed in /usr/local, but your configure is looking in /usr instead. Please check the config.log for the exact information on what happened.

Comment: It's been a while. I tried to set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH... But it did not change anything...

Comment: What did you set in the PKG_CONFIG_PATH? Did you install pcre with libraries and headers on your OS X ("port install pcre")?

Comment: No I compiled it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/pkgconfig/

or equivalent depending on where the pcre files are found